# Не получается получить несколько параметров из fields, vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Ситуация такая: мне необходимо обрабатывать пользователя, и вытянуть из его страницы определенные данные. При попытке указать в fields более одного параметра у меня затираются все, кроме последнего. Т.е. вот такая конструкция выдает мне в параметрах только универ

```
friends = vk.method("friends.get", 
{
    "user_id" : target,
    "name_case" : "nom",
    "fields" : 
    [
        "bdate", "city", "country",
        "domain", "education", "nickname",
        "last_seen", "universities"
    ]
})['items']
```

При попытке сделать отдельный вызов для каждого параметра - я ну очень сильно теряю во времени. Есть у кого-то идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй такой код:

```
friends = vk.method("friends.get", 
{
    "user_id" : target,
    "name_case" : "nom",
    "fields" : "bdate,city,country,...,universities"
    ]
})['items']
```

Comment: спасибо большое, работает